# Error Run app with image

Tags: android, image

My code run without any picture but when I add an image in background and run the app in my phone. The error says - the app has stopped.
My code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/apple_01">
```

My image's name is `apple_01`.

Comment: Share the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be getting a OutOfMemoryExeption try to lower the pixel size of the drawable, you can use photoshop or any other software to shrink the image size

Comment: I tested this image in another app and run but in this app don't set any image

Comment: do you have any other imageviews on your layout? on a blank activity your image may work but if you start to add more, you may run out of memory, i think this is what is happening since you said that the image works on a different app

Comment: in this layout don't have any imageview this image is background 

In this layout I just have two text views and one button

Comment: when run the program don't show any errors but don't open app in my device and write app has stopped

Comment: if the app stops working you should be able to see an error in your Android Monitor LogCat

Answer (score 0):

You should try with another pic from file drawable such as

`@drawable/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha`

if your app run correctly you should exchange the image